# After converting byte array image not displaying core.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my detail view, to show more information about (in my case a Task), I will display an `Image`. Currently the image will not show in the view. What's wrong?

Here is my code:

My `ActionResult` in the controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowImage(int id)
{
    var task = _context.Task.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
    Image image = byteArrayToImage(task.Image);
    return View(image);
}
```

The converter method:

```
private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

And my View:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage", new { id = Model.ID } )" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Here is a print screen of the return. See the image for the output, it looks fine.

[image: See the image for the output, it looks fine]

Comment: So how does the `img` tag get rendered? The first thing you need to work out is whether it's the HTML requesting the image that's broken or the code fetching the image. (It doesn't help that we have no idea what `_context.Task` is.)

Comment: @JonSkeet the IMG tag stays static in my view, no rendering. Every task has it's own ID. To get the information inside the Task and in my case the task.Image, that's why I use the _context.Task.

Comment: "the IMG tag stays static in my view, no rendering" - it's not clear what you mean by that. The `img` tag clearly *should* change based on the task ID, so what are you actually seeing? Please clarify in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [`FileContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to return a file from your action. Your action then becomes as simple as:

```
public IActionResult ShowImage(int id)
{
    var task = _context.Task.SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);

    return File(task.Image, "image/jpeg");    //TODO: Set Content-Type appropriately
}
```

**Note:**

1. You should set the `contentType` parameter appropriately in the above (I have *guessed*).
2. In the above code, I am using the [`ControllerBase.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.0) Method to return a `FileContentResult`. If your controller does not inherit from `Controller` or `ControllerBase` you will need to return a `FileContentResult` directly.

Comment: Your solution was ight. Works like a charm! Thank you!